# Pymongo nested loop two cursor object not working

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I might be dumb but I have two cursor objects returned by query result `users` and `locations`

```
    user_count = 0
    location_count = 0
    for user in users:
        print(user)  ## prints every object correctly
        user_count = user_count + 1
        for location in locations:
            print(location) ##only loops once on the first user
            location_count = location_count + 1

    print(user_count, location_count)   ## 1720 39
```

the inner loop user seems only executed once while the outer loop behaves as expected.

the output of the above code:

```
#prints the first user
#prints all locations 
#prints all remaining users
! missing locations
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `locations` is a cursor, it will be an iterable, not a list, array, or dict.  It will be traversed with `next`, and MongoDB cursors do not provide any `reset` or `rewind`.

After it loops through for the first user, the cursor is exhausted, so for the subsequent users the loop ends immediately.

You might try reading the cursor into a list before the loop, like

```
locations = list(db.collection.find())
```

The you should be able to loop over that list multiple times.